# /bin/sh - echo >> operator not working as expected

Tags: shell, shell-script, escape-characters

I'm writing a shell script that appends binary contents to a file. I tried using this command:

```
echo -en '\x61\x62\x63..' >> /tmp/myfile
```

but that caused the following output:

```
-en \x61\x62\x63..
```

Is there any way I could append the contents to a file rather than having to remove all contents every time?

**Note**

I'm trying to do this on a system that *only* has `/bin/sh`, this command works fine with `bash` but not when using the default shell.

Comment: You want to print `'\x61\x62\x63..'` or print `'abc..'` to /tmp/myfile?

Comment: @cuonglm "abc.." but the hex could be any binary (including nullbytes and such), however rocky just answered my question, thanks anyways!

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/4667 and Stéphane Chazelas's comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, `echo` is a builtin function, so you are getting that behavior. <strike>In sh it is not a builtin</strike>. Looks like *sh* uses its builtin "echo" command which is different.

So try using `/bin/echo` rather than without the `/bin/`.

Comment: Is there a way I could still do this with another command? I found something about printf but I cant seem to get that working either

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with portability, you can't use [echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) or [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html), both treat escape sequences `\xXX` unspecified as POSIX defined.

Even in GNU system, the behavior of `echo`, either builtin or `/bin/echo` can be alter. You can try:

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo -en '\x61'
-en \x61

$ env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash -c "echo -en '\x61'"
-en a
```

(You should read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/38906) for more details).

With standard POSIX tool chest, you can use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%c%c%c..", 97, 98, 99}'
abc..
```